# Cassandra UDF: getting error on checking null values

Tags: java, cassandra, user-defined-functions

I wrote an UDF like the below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myspace.getValue(lng bigint, dbl double, etc double) RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS 'if (lng != null) {return (double)lng;} else if (dbl != null) { return dbl;} else return etc;';
```

And I get this error:

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Java source compilation failed:
> Line 1: The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) long, null
> Line 1: The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null"

While in manuals these comparisons seems ok (e.g. [here](https://github.com/chbatey/cassandra-examples/blob/master/UDFs.cql)).
I am using Cassandra 4.0.3 (through its docker image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I changed `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` to `CALLED ON NULL INPUT` and it is ok now and works as I expect :)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a Java question more than a Cassandra question.

Both `double` and `long` are primitive Java data types and are assigned a default value if not initialised (`0L` or `0.0d` respectively) so they can't be `null`.

For more information, see [Java Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Cheers!

Comment: I know differences between primitive types and objects. As can be seen in the accepted answer, by changing the command it became ok.